# How to get Not Licensed when testing LVL with android before publishing

Tags: android, android-lvl

So I have been battling with this for some time and I need your help with it. I added the licensing code to my application, uploaded the application but didn't publish it. so I think it is called a "draft" now. I need to test licensing before making it available. I am using my google account (publisher account) in my phone so no test accounts are involved.

The thing that, when run the application on my device (through eclipse to device) it always gets the Licensed Code so it is successfull. I want to test the "Not Licensed" case. I went to the edit profile and made the static code to be not licensed. However, I still keep getting the "licensed OK". I tried removing the app, and rerunning it but same answer.

PLEAAAAE help me, how can I test all the conditions? I keep getting the same status code over and over again
Thank you

Anyone? Comon, there have to be someone who successfully tested LVL. At least point me to how I can debug the problem

Comment: How did you resolve that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I guess you have to run the app using the first account you signed in with the phone and add it as test account to the website.Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 1):

Just Want to make one thing sure... You uploaded the application and did not publish.. So it is saved in your drafts. But did you click the activate button near the apk file(when you uploaded it). May be you might have forgotten to do so.. Please check it for once. and then try...

All the Best

Comment: Oh I didn't click the activate button. Is that step required? I was afraide that if I click the button it will publish my app. IT will not publish my app, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this worked for me. Add the account that google talk uses. As far as I can tell you have to wipe your phone to change that account.

Also wait a minute between tests.